# how to duplicate a file in the same folder with a different name in apple script?

Tags: copy, applescript, duplicates

I have a file "My File.txt" in a folder "My Folder"
I want to make 100 copies of that file in the same folder "My Folder" named "My File 1.txt", "My File 2.txt", "My File 3.txt"and so on.

I have close to 0 experience in apple script so if anyone can send me a complete snippet I would appreciate it.

Thanks a lot,

Trevor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this ago, it's a bit more complicated then it needs to be with the auto name and extension extracting, but it should serve as guide to scripting the Finder.

Key is to set the path to your file at the top of the script.

```
set master_file to POSIX file "/Users/trevor/Desktop/My Folder/My File.txt"

tell application "Finder"
    set master_dir to (container of file master_file)
    set root_nm to the name of file master_file
    set ext to the name extension of file master_file
    set root_nm to characters 1 thru ((the offset of ext in root_nm) - 2) of root_nm as text

    repeat with counter from 1 to 100

        with timeout of 10 seconds -- may need more time for big files
            set err to false
            try
                set duplicated_file to duplicate master_file to master_dir
            on error msg
                log ("ERROR DUPLICATING file " & counter & " : " & msg)
                set err to true
            end try
        end timeout

        if (not err) then -- try and rename it.
            try
                set the name of duplicated_file to (root_nm & " " & counter & "." & ext)
            on error msg
                log ("ERROR RENAMING file " & counter & " : " & msg)
            end try
        end if

    end repeat

end tell

say "Finished"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set dir to (POSIX file "/Users/username/My Folder") as alias
    repeat 100 times
        duplicate file "My File.txt" of dir to dir
    end repeat
end tell
```

You could also run a command like this in Terminal:

```
for i in {1..100};do cp ~/My\ Folder/My\ File.txt ~/My\ Folder/My\ File\ $i.txt;done
```